# What is wrong with my code that data retrieving from database using prepare

Tags: php, html, pdo, prepare

this is my php code for retrieving data from database using prepare statement

```
if ($conn) { //database connected success

$view_sql = "SELECT * FROM certificate_verify";
$stmt_view = $conn->prepare($view_sql);
$stmt_view->execute();

$results_view = $stmt_view->fetchAll();

foreach($results_view as $row) {

    $view_first_name = $row['first_name'];
    $view_last_name = $row['last_name'];
}
```

I need to fetch all data from database to display in the following display page

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $view_first_name; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $view_last_name; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

but I am getting only last row data (not all data from database) why it is happening and what is wrong with my code?

Comment: you'll need to wrap up the whole `<tr>` inside the `foreach`, use `echo` inside it

Comment: You need to set your  <tr></tr> in foreach loop

Answer (score 2):

Use foreach loop inside your table as otherwise you data ovetlap inside foreach loop and you get only last value

```
<?php
$results_view = $stmt_view->fetchAll();
?>
<table>
    <?php foreach ($results_view as $row) { ?>// start your loop here
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['first_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['last_name']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>// loop end
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

replace your `foreach(...){...}` code with this:

```
echo "<table>";
foreach ($results_view as $row)
{
  echo "<tr>";
  foreach ($row as $cell)
  {
    echo "<td>".$cell."</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score -1):

Obviously,
Because every time you iterate your `foreach` loop, your `$view_first_name` and `$view_last_name` get overwritten with new values coming from `$row`.
You need to make `$view_first_name` and `$view_last_name` `Array` and iterate those over `tr`.